# In Ionic2,my tabs dont shown

Tags: ionic2

I am trying to show tabs on android but not shown

it is shown on web page

Where is the problem

My code is ->

> html part:

```
  <ion-tabs>
<ion-tab tabIcon="water" tabTitle="Water" [root]="Tabroot1"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab tabIcon="leaf" tabTitle="Life" [root]="Tabroot2"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab tabIcon="flame" tabTitle="Fire" [root]="Tabroot3"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab tabIcon="magnet" tabTitle="Force" [root]="Tabroot4"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

> typscript part

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';

import {IsimPage} from '../game/isim/isim';  
import {SehirPage} from '../game/sehir/sehir';
import {HayvanPage} from '../game/hayvan/hayvan';
import {BitkiPage} from '../game/bitki/bitki';
 @Component({
  selector:'page-yeniOyun',
  templateUrl:'yeniOyun.html'
})
export class YeniOyunPage{
Tabroot1: any
Tabroot2: any
Tabroot3: any
Tabroot4: any
constructor(public naVCtrl: NavController){
    this.Tabroot1 = IsimPage;
    this.Tabroot2 = SehirPage;
    this.Tabroot3 = HayvanPage;
    this.Tabroot4 = BitkiPage;
 }
}
```

Comment: any error in console? do you use any JavaScript reference in your index.html?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you '**Dag**'.I solved problem in differen way and solve is about my ionic html structure.
Typescipt part and html part true,wrong is my tabs page

> html part:

```
<ion-tabs>
 <ion-tab tabIcon="water" tabTitle="Water" [root]="Tabroot1"></ion-tab>
 <ion-tab tabIcon="leaf" tabTitle="Life" [root]="Tabroot2"></ion-tab> 
 <ion-tab tabIcon="flame" tabTitle="Fire" [root]="Tabroot3"></ion-tab>
 <ion-tab tabIcon="magnet" tabTitle="Force" [root]="Tabroot4"></ion-tab>
```

> typescript part

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';

import {IsimPage} from '../game/isim/isim';  
import {SehirPage} from '../game/sehir/sehir';
import {HayvanPage} from '../game/hayvan/hayvan';
import {BitkiPage} from '../game/bitki/bitki';
@Component({
 selector:'page-yeniOyun',
 templateUrl:'yeniOyun.html'
})
export class YeniOyunPage{
Tabroot1: any
Tabroot2: any
Tabroot3: any
Tabroot4: any
constructor(public naVCtrl: NavController){
  this.Tabroot1 = IsimPage;
  this.Tabroot2 = SehirPage;
  this.Tabroot3 = HayvanPage;
  this.Tabroot4 = BitkiPage;
 }
}
```

> IsimPage:

```
 <ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
 <ion-title>
    IsimPage
 </ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
  <ion-content padding>
   //Mytab interface here
  </ion-content>
```

> SehirPage:

```
 <ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
 <ion-title>
    SehirPage
 </ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
  <ion-content padding>
   //Mytab interface here
  </ion-content>
```

> HayvanPage:

```
 <ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
 <ion-title>
    HayvanPage
 </ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
  <ion-content padding>
   //Mytab interface here
  </ion-content>
```

> BitkiPage:

```
 <ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
 <ion-title>
    BitkiPge
 </ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
  <ion-content padding>
   //Mytab interface here
  </ion-content>
```